# What statistical method to use? Heat treatment of bacterial spores

Tags: self-study, biostatistics

Here is my experimental design;

I have four different strains of a bacterial spores.

I am taking a fixed volume of spore suspension of these strains and subjecting them to heat treatment at the same temperature (50 C).

At time points 0, 15, 30 and 60 minutes I am removing fixed volumes of the spores and growing them on agar plates to see how they recover in response to heat treatment. I have taken 3 values for each strain at each timepoint (biological replicate - carried out the same treatment 3 times on each strain at each timepoint to get a mean).

The fixed aliquots taken at each time point are serially diluted and 4 dilutions are put on to plates. Then the dilution that has the most readable visual counts (number of bacterial colonies) is used. This value is transformed by multiplying by the dilution factor to obtain a value of colony forming units (CFU/ml). This is a fairly standard approach in microbial culture and I hope my explanation was satisfactory. So the count is continuous and it can't go below zero. It is not a percentage

My aim is to carry out statistical analysis and see whether there are statistically significant differences between the values at each timepoint within each group (intergroup). I am not interested in comparing data between groups (strain). I am looking for recommendations for the best statistical test to do this.

Comment: Can you say more? What is "triplicate data", eg? Variation of what within ribotypes? Etc.

Comment: (To whom it may concern, this question seems to be asking about what test to use, which is on topic. Just mentioning GraphPad shouldn't make this off topic.)

Comment: Apologies for any ambiguity. At each time point there are three biological replicates for each strain of the organism.                                                                          The variation I quote is the difference in number of microorganisms being recovered in each strain, the experiment involved heat treatment and seeing at each time point how many bacteria are viable.

Comment: What does that mean, exactly? Do you have 3 different cells harvested from each animal? What is the variable you want to know the variation of? Please add more information about your situation, your data, & your goals here. Please edit your question to include the information there. (Since people are voting to close this as off topic just because your post mentions GraphPad, you might also delete your first sentence.)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. What are the measurements exactly? Ie, after 15 minutes of heat, you are growing bacterium A on 3 different plates & measuring what, the number of cells counted under a microscope, the mass of the cells, their florescence in response to a die, something else? How is whatever you're measuring distributed? Is it a count, is it continuous, can it go below 0, is it bounded (eg, a %)?

Comment: The fixed aliquots taken at each time point are serially diluted and 4 dilutions are put on to plates. Then the dilution that has the most readable visual counts (number of bacterial colonies) is used. This value is transformed by multiplying by the dilution factor to obtain a value of colony forming units (CFU/ml). This is a fairly standard approach in microbial culture and I hope my explanation was satisfactory. So the count is continuous and it can't go below zero. It is not a percentage

Comment: Some of these clarifying comments really belong in the body of the question itself (though I have voted to reopen).

Comment: Add some details to the title, otherwise it is not informative at all...

Comment: Do you expect to see any zero counts? Will 60 minutes at 50C kill everything?

Comment: Sorry David, I simplified the experimental method by changing the word 'spore' to bacteria to make it conceptually easier to understand to non-biologists. The experiments used bacterial endospores.

Comment: So you don't expect any zero counts, right?

Comment: It is theoretically possible if all the spores were inactivated but it is very unlikely unless I used much higher temperatures. So the answer is no